# When should an object contain other objects vs. references to other objects?

Tags: javascript, oop

Are there certain situations in which one method is better than the other or is there an acceptable "best practice?"  Take the following for example:

```
project:{
  team:{
    testers:{
      1 : {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
      2 : {first: 'employee', last: 'two'}
    },
    experts:{
      1 : {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
      3 : {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
    }
  }
};
employees:{
  1 : {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
  2 : {first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
  3 : {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
};
```

vs

```
project:{
  team:{
    testers:[1,2],
    experts:[1,3]
  }
};
employees:{
  1 : {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
  2 : {first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
  3 : {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
};
```

vs

```
project:{
  team:{
    testers:[
      {id: 1, first: 'first', last: 'one'},
      {id: 2, first: 'employee', last: 'two'}
    ],
    experts:{
      {id: 1, first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
      {id: 3, first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
    }
  }
};
employees:[
  {id: 1, first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
  {id: 2, first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
  {id: 3, first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
];
```

Let's add a very specific situation.  I am using a handlebars template combined with a multiselect.  I want to create a multiselect listing all employees eligible to be an expert while also preselecting employees that have already been identified as experts on the project.  If I was using **EXAMPLE 3** I would have to do the following to build my multiselect:

```
 for(var x in employees){
   var found = 0;
   for(var y in project.team.experts){
     if(project.team.experts.[y] === employees[x].id){
        found = 1;
     }
   }
   if(found){
      //Print selected option
   } else {
     //Print unselected option
   }
 }
```

However, if I am using **EXAMPLE 1**:

```
for(var x in employees){
  if(typeof project.team.experts[employees[x].id] !== 'undefined'){
    //Print selected option
  } else {
    //Print unselected option
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the second choice, but this question is Opinion based?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it depends on what you will use the objects for.
You can use (json) objects to send to an API, to feed a template, to communicate between objects, to extract values depending on needs, etc...

The major thing about the format is that this:

```
employees:{
  1 : {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
  2 : {first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
  3 : {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
};
```

Makes more sense in the following format:

```
employees: [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "Kim"}];
```

because employees is a collection of objects (an array) rather than a single object.
This will make it a lot easier for you to extract the data or perform manipulations on the object.
I'm not sure what the `first` and `last`parameters are supposed to mean, but I think that it is also a good idea to make the object properties descriptive (give them clear names).

But I think that it is very situation dependent.
It might as well happen that one day, you need to send an object in the following format as a URL search parameter in order to comply with a certain api's requirements:

```
{employees: "1, 2, 3"}
```

Comment: Does storing employees like employees: [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "Kim"}] mean that anywhere I would reference employees (such as a multiselect) mean that I will be referencing employee by array key versus id?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Generally the id is used as an identifier for the entity and matches the id of a persistent data store. Unless the object was not saved to the datastore yet; in that case the employees don't have an id allocated yet.

Comment: Updated my question to include a specific scenario.

Comment: I believe that these are typical tradeoff decisions where you choose between optimal efficiency, or where you choose for optimal efficiency against ease of readability and maintenance and following standards. If both solutions work, then they are by definition not logically incorrect. You will however notice that using objects as properties, instead of using an array as a single list property is not common practice, which will bring you in trouble later, also when communicating with a back end. -> See further in next comment

Comment: Personally I use the Underscore.js library, which offers a list of convenience methods on arrays, collection etc, and which offers nice syntax for solving these common problems. I highly recommend it, it offers you very readable and clean syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If by references you mean index arrays (`[1, 2]`) then doing that is risky... It will reduce the readability of your code.

Simply compare:

```
// Directly gives me the employee
project.team.testers[1];

// I have to pass an index to the employee
employees[project.team.testers[1]];
```

A field called `testers` should contain testers, that is to say employees, not indices into an array or hash of employees, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up the terminology a bit. Objects never contain other objects, they contain *references* to other objects. But this *reference* has different semantic that the *reference* in your question title. Which is some kind of `id` with external means to resolve it to the instance.

Next, in your first example you actually have *two* employees with `last:'one'`. `project.team.testers[1]` and `project.team.experts[1]` are reference *different* objects.

Next, you're using numbers as keys. This is not so good as it's easy to mistaken an object for an array here (and then wonder why experts[0] is non-existent).

Now, to your question. The first snippet is quite natural.

As for the second snippet, instead of referencing object directly you set some ids which you'll need to resolve later on. The question is, what are the reasons to do so - or when would it make sense/be necessary. What I can imagine:

- Ids are somehow natural to the objects (like employee id).
- Id/object maping is somehow "central" to the application.
- Ids live longer that object instances.
- There are no hard references to the target objects so they can be garbage collected.
- If not using the id you'd actually need to create a *copy* of the target object so using ids actually saves you memory and it is important.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false dichotomy. You may be thinking in relational database modeling terms. You just need:

```
var employees: [
    {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
    {first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
    {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
];

var project = {
    team:{
        testers: [employees[0], employees[1]],
        experts: [employees[0], employees[2]]
    }
};
```

In other words, instead of storing indices or arrays of indices, just store references to the objects themselves.

If you prefer, `employees` could be a hash, such as:

```
var employees = {
    employeeOne:   {first: 'employee', last: 'one'},
    employeeTwo:   {first: 'employee', last: 'two'},
    employeeThree: {first: 'employee', last: 'three'}
};

var project = {
    team:{
        testers: [employeeOne, employeeTwo],
        experts: [employeeOne, employeeThree]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using indexes instead of references, because:

1. You can load data from server easily, because you don't need make reference;
2. You be safere, because when you delete object you can forget remove all reference therefore get harder to catching bug;
3. You can  sort or filter data easily, because all what you need - get array with right indexes order:

   project:{
     team:{
       testers:[1,2,5,6,9],
       experts:[1,3]
     },
     teamSortedСontribution:{
       testers:[9,5,1,2,6],
       experts:[3,1]
     },
     teamFiltratedJavascript:{
       testers:[9,5],
       experts:[1]
     }
   };
4. If you use node.js and keep reference between object and try scaling you programm, you can faced with trouble, because node.js haven't shared memory.